# Google Maps API data.remove not working

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to remove a feature from a data layer but keep getting the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'getId'

Here's my geojson:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -96.9780201,
                33.0492263
            ]
        },
        "id": "0",
        "properties": {
            "description": "800 Block College Street"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -97.0106445,
                33.0225452
            ]
        },
        "id": "1",
        "properties": {
            "description": "1700 Block Edmond"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -96.994174,
                33.046233
            ]
        },
        "id": "2",
        "properties": {
            "description": "Logon/Cruthfield"
        }
    }
]
```

}

In my javascript I'm using:

```
map.data.remove(1)
```

Any ideas?  I don't see any examples online for removing features though it is listed in the documentation at:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to delete feature with id 1 than you have to call

```
map.data.remove(map.data.getFeatureById("1"));
```

remove() expects  Data.Feature

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I also just found that you can remove all of the features by doing: map.data.forEach(function(_feature){         map.data.remove(_feature);        });

Comment: is this really the best way to remove all the features? is there no wholesale way to dump it?

Comment: oh I remember now, I did find a way you can do map.data.setMap(null); map.data = new google.maps.Data({map:map}); map.data.setMap(map);